# Only retrieve words with 8 or less characters ending in "ing" from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm needing to only retrieve words with 8 or less characters and also ending in "ing" from a MySQL database.

I'm using php and would appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Pretty easy with a LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%ing' AND LENGTH(field) <= 8
```

Comment: you should also look at @Ashalynd response: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: @ermagana RegEx is an overkill for this. There are claims that it is less performant that LIKE (http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/), especially over large data sets. Depending on the size, Full Text with MATCH...AGAINST may be a better option because of the index, but otherwise for such a simple comparison I think this is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field RLIKE '^.{0,5}[iI][nN][gG]$';
```

Comment: this is an interesting implementation, i wasn't aware that mysql could handle regular expressions

Comment: thanks for the link, i found it as well and I also noticed that the pattern isn't case sensitive unless using binary strings: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: True, but in general nothing prevents you from treating the text field as binary for collation purposes.

Comment: RegEx seems like an overkill. There are performance concerns with larger datasets too.

Answer (score -1):

`Select column from
Table
Where column like '%ing' and Length( column ) <=8`

Using regular expression

`Select column 
From table
Where column REGEXP   '^.{0,5}ing$'`

REGEXP is not case sensitive is will take care of both upper and lower case characters

Comment: This answer has already been proposed, with better formatting.

Comment: I am posting frm Android phone keyboard is troublesome